# Can we sneak BLE-Mesh-Device using BT packets log with WireShark and write the sniffed commands via nRFconnect App?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, bluetooth-peripheral

https://medium.com/@urish/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-lightbulb-56580fcb7546

Using the above link, I did try to hack and control a BLE Device which works in BLE-Mesh-Network, But it failed.
Came here by looking for help to Know the possibility of this idea as whether this is at least will workout in real world scenario.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If your goal is to just capture on air packets and decode them, then this is technically doable as BLE mesh uses standard LE Advertising so you should be able to capture the advertising packets. However, there is a lot of security that is inherently involved with mesh and it would be extremely difficult to decode the communication, unlike the example used in the link, unless you fully understand the mesh protocol and its different layers and security procedures.

Comment: [https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-mesh-security-overview?_ga=2.165662457.716073564.1550042655-1470846237.1550042655] Hi Youssif, really thank you for the hint given about security layers involved in BLE-Mesh-communication protocol.  I thought to hack a BLE-Mesh bulb with the Sneaked BT Commands Re-Play method, but unable to do it and found the above link by surfed internet with your hint. I have stopped that hack experiment. Great help from you at the right time (I have wasted a week without knowing this). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad this was helpful.